# Jquery in IE, fully messed up

Tags: jquery

I am using the [nivo slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) in one of my website, the slider looks perfect in Firefox, but in IE 7, 8 its height is increased upto 1006px, the slider works, but the height has increased a lot, I have deactivated all the plugins, still its viewing the same, but in my localhost it works in IE also, but I cant differentiate the actual problem in it, here is the site http://www.marqueehireauckland.net.nz/

Can anyone help me in this?

My nivo slider code is this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
    </script>



<div style="margin-top:-75px;">
            <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                    <div class="ribbon"></div>
                    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/header.jpg" alt="" width="1002"/>
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/header1.jpg" alt="" width="1002" />
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/header2.jpg" alt="" width="1002"/>
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/header4.jpg" alt="" width="1002"/>
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/header5.jpg" alt="" width="1002"/>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

EDIT:
I have fixed this. 
Thank you

Comment: Please either delete this question or post an answer with what you did to fix your problem so that others who maybe having the same issue may be helped by your answer.

Comment: OK, I ll post an answer to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long debugging, I found that the class `.nivoSlider` was not having a definite height, so I gave a height `height:288px !important;` and woila, it worked,